# Template fails to parse on GoogleCloudDataflow when using the Labels option

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Dataflow project and I set my GoogleCloudOptions like this:

```
google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
google_cloud_options.project = my_settings.gcp_project_name
google_cloud_options.job_name = "{}-{}".format(my_settings.gcp_job_name, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d-%H-%M"))
google_cloud_options.staging_location = 'gs://some/staging'
google_cloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://some/temp'
google_cloud_options.template_location = 'gs://some/templates/some_template'
google_cloud_options.labels = ["dum=dum", "run=run"]

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/some_project/templates:launch?alt=json&gcsPath=gs%3A%2F%2Fsome%2Ftemplates%2Fsome_template returned "Unable to parse template file 'gs://some/templates/some_template'.">
```

That fails horribly.

```
google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
google_cloud_options.project = my_settings.gcp_project_name
google_cloud_options.job_name = "{}-{}".format(my_settings.gcp_job_name, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d-%H-%M"))
google_cloud_options.staging_location = 'gs://some/staging'
google_cloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://some/temp'
google_cloud_options.labels = ["dum=dum", "run=run"]
```

This actually runs, why is that? Ideally I would like for the templated version to run and I need to figure out how to make the template compile and parse properly.

```
google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
google_cloud_options.project = my_settings.gcp_project_name
google_cloud_options.job_name = "{}-{}".format(my_settings.gcp_job_name, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y-%m-%d-%H-%M"))
google_cloud_options.staging_location = 'gs://some/staging'
google_cloud_options.temp_location = 'gs://some/temp'
google_cloud_options.template_location = 'gs://some/templates/some_template'
```

This runs as well.

So to me it seems as if adding the labels option in conjunction with template_location option causes Dataflow to fail.

Comment: Does it work fine without labels? Your question title implies that it does, but the body of the question implies that it runs fine without templates, not without labels.

Comment: Yes, it works without labels both ways. But it only works with labels in the non-templated version.

Comment: I want it to work with labels templated and non-templated.

Comment: Can you post the full error stack trace, rather than just the error message? Also, does the error happen when *creating* the template, or when *launching* it afterwards? (the error message seems to imply launching) How are you launching it - from the UI or somehow else? Does the staged template file appear to be a valid JSON file?

Comment: @jkff The error happens launching it afterwards. I have verified that the json for the template is valid after it is pushed to gcp. I do not launch from the ui. I use the googleapiclient build method to build a service object, I then add my custom template parameters to the request body. I authenticate with a service account. I will attach that code below.

Comment: https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/5f8ee545-bf59-4d03-9d77-13610b150467/?i=true

I have created a pyfiddle so you can view the code I am using to launch the template after creating it.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "execute_template.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(parsed.filename)
  File "execute_template.py", line 33, in main
    response = request.execute()
  File "/Users/Private/Private/Private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oauth2client/util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Private/Private/Private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 842, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)

Comment: googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/some_project/templates:launch?alt=json&gcsPath=gs%3A%2F%2Fsome_location%2Ftemplates%2Fsome_template returned "Unable to parse template file 'gs://some_location/templates/some_template'.">

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what is going on. I've passed this to someone on the team who might help.

Comment: thanks for your help @jkff

Comment: Hello @jkff I was wondering if that person was going to be able to help?

Comment: @JermellBeane I'm looking into your issue and try to reproduce. Will give you an update this afternoon. Thanks.

Comment: @ZhouYunqing I could provide you with a copy of my template if you need it. Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a json serialization compability issue. The backend failed to recognize the serialized label map.

I'm working to see if it can be fixed on our side but it may need quite a bit to roll out.
As a mitigation, in short term you can do replacements as the following in the template file (there should be 2 occurrences).
FROM:

```
"labels": {"foo" : "bar"}
```

TO:

```
"labels": [{"key" : "foo"}, {"value" : "bar"}]
```

And see if it works. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: so I made the changes but the dataflow job will fail with [this error now.](https://i.imgur.com/2A630vq.png)

Comment: Let me take a look into that and report it back to you shortly.

Comment: I tried it locally using BEAM 2.2 and it seems to work. I drafted a script to do the replacement, could you please take a try? I agree its a bit hacky and we are working on a permanent fix. The fix shouldn't need changes on SDK side AFAICT. The link to the script: https://pastebin.com/crrNhvPJ

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert_template.py", line 15, in <module>
    template_json['environment']['sdkPipelineOptions']['options']['labels'] = ChangeDictFormat(template_json['environment']['sdkPipelineOptions']['options']['labels'])
  File "convert_template.py", line 6, in ChangeDictFormat
    for k, v in obj.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: interesting. This line is trying to replace the dict shown here https://imgur.com/a/tQ0tD , are you working on the original template or your modified one? Sorry for frustration.

Comment: Working on an original.

Comment: current options look like:

`google_cloud_options.labels = ['something=foo','something_else=pizza']`

Comment: could you please show me how your label field look like in the result template file? Thanks.

Comment: only the top level `labels` option looks as if that code works on it. The option that is failing has the same form as I input in the code so... `labels:['something=foo','something_else=pizza']`

Comment: Sorry for confusion. It turns out python sdk generates this section in a different way. I've corrected the script and verified it worked for me w/ beam python. Link to updated script: https://pastebin.com/WUNfG84u . Updates for permanent fix will be posted here. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: I have verified that the conversion script now works. Going to try to run the template against my data. Will update later today.

Comment: Glad to know it works. We've located the bug in our service and fixed in the code base. But it may need a couple of weeks to be in production. (subject to changes in rollout schedules). No code changes are necessary on your side because it is not a sdk bug.

Comment: We've fully fixed the issue on the service side and you should no longer need the mitigation script. Sorry for inconvenience.